# how to make a first-class object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, first-class

After reading about the first class object i decided to make my new first-class object like a function but with another name. i searched and found many thing about functions in javascript.

---

## conclusions from my research

1) that every function is an object and can also be treated like an object.

look here on code:

```
var myfunc3 = new Function(
                 "a", " return a + 1;");
```

from page [`this`](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1028-javascript-jems-first-class-functions.html)

as far as i know that any function defined before can be called by using `new` constructor that is:

```
    var person = function(name, age){
       this.name=name;
       this.age = age;
}
```

now i can call this by using `new` that is:

```
var x = new person("tom", 34);
```

so from the above example i can say that a function defined earlier and then with `new` can be called again!

---

### What i don't know

1) how function uses its round brackets,

2) cannot understand the line `Function( "a", " return a + 1;");`

3) How can we implement function?

---

i know you will surely dislike this question but i want to do this because i want to understand every expact of JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the `Function` constructor? Ewww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This is the syntax for calling functions, defined in the language.

```
f(a); // calls the function "f" with the argument "a"
```

2) Functions are first-class objects, meaning they can be passed around just like any other object and like other objects they have a constructor, `Function`. The `Function` constructor creates a new function by **evaling** the code in a new isolate scope, so you don't have access to the surrounding variables. Again, the `Function` is a form of `eval`, avoid it, this is not the way to create functions in JavaScript.

3) You don't implement a function. A function is an object that is already implemented. There are two ways of creating functions in JavaScript. A function declaration:

```
function f(){}
```

And a function expression:

```
var f = function(){};
```

The difference is about hoisting. See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question,

1. Round Brackets are Syntax, which holds arguments.
2. It might be a function named `Function` that accepts two arguments.
3. You can implement a function by using the arguments and doing some logic inside the function and you can also return something using `return` keyword.

For example:

Function without `return`:

```
function Hi(name){
  alert("Hi "+name);
} // Calling it like this: Hi("John"); will alert "Hi John"
```

And function that returns:

```
function Hi(name){
  return "Hi "+name;
}// You can store what's returned in a variable like this: var text=Hi("John");alert(text);
```